# Mounting CIFS as user in Ubuntu 16.04 returns "No such file or directory"

Tags: mount, fstab

I recently upgraded from (X)ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 (meaning a complete new installation, nothing left on hard drive). For the past years, I had the following line in my */etc/fstab*:

```
//home.server/Development /home/user/development  cifs noauto,user,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,dir_mode=0555,file_mode=0644  0 0
```

And I could mount it manually, no problem.

Since 16.04. however, when trying to mount the CIFS target with normal user rights, I get the following error:

```
 user:~$ mount //some.server/Development
 mount: //some.server/Development: No such file or directory

 user:~$ mount "//some.server/Development"
 mount: //some.server/Development: No such file or directory
```

However, if I repeat the command with *sudo* everything works and the CIFS target is mounted.

What I've tried so far:

- I checked *man fstab* and *man mount*, but their description of the *user* option hasn't changed
- I checked that */sbin/mount.cifs* has the SUID flag set
- I removed one by one all options from the line, to check whether one was creating the problem
- I moved *.smbcredentials* to an unencrypted partition
- I changed *user* option to the less save *users* option
- *mount.cifs* version is *6.4*

None of the above has improved the situation.
And I don't want to automount the CIFS as it would request to store the *.smbcredentials* file in an unencrypted partition. Additionally, I would have to make some workarounds to assure the network is up before mounting.

Has anyone an idea what else I may try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be possible any longer by default on Xubuntu 16.04 -- There is a note on the [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) Ubuntu Help Wiki that offers a workaround though:

> Note: Regretfully as from version 3.3.2-1ubuntu3.2 (October 2009) this approach is no longer possible together with the "user" option. A security fix prevents reading the credentials file if you don't have read access to it. You will have to pin the packages at version 3.3.2-1ubuntu3 or 3.3.2-1ubuntu3.1 to continue using this approach as non-root.