# Why do I get the error: "mount[1328]: error 2 (No such file or directory) opening credential file /home/username/.smbcredentials"

Tags: 16.04, samba, encryption, automount, cifs

Before this issue, I was using version Ubuntu 15.10, but upgraded to 16.04 and was able to auto mount to my samba shares successfully using the default instructions provided at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently.  Since then, I rebuilt my system from scratch and decided to use encryption, all is well until I added my entries to the fstab file?  I have tried several suggestions/workarounds out here on this site and googling for anything related to my issue, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.  I ran into this response, but not sure if this is the reason?

[Mounting CIFS as user in Ubuntu 16.04 returns "No such file or directory"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790249/mounting-cifs-as-user-in-ubuntu-16-04-returns-no-such-file-or-directory)

"A security fix prevents reading the credentials file if you don't have read access to it."

Comment: If your smbcredentials are stored in an encrypted home directory, then you won't be able to mount the share until after you have logged in - that's  not really the same as not having read access, IMHO

Comment: thank you for your response @steeldriver  i guess i have to settle for "sudo mount -a" once logged in then.